# If there is a single copy of a DLL in memory, how can it be loaded into an application's memory space?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, dynamic-linking

The page [Create C/C++ DLLs in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/dlls-in-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019) says the following in its second paragraph:

> A DLL isn't a stand-alone executable. DLLs run in the context of the
>   applications that call them. **The operating system loads the DLL into
>   an application's memory space**. It's done either when the application
>   is loaded (implicit linking), or on demand at runtime (explicit
>   linking). DLLs also make it easy to share functions and resources
>   across executables. Multiple applications can access the contents of a
>   single copy of a DLL in memory at the same time.

Is the sentence highlighted above correct? How can this statement be reconciled with the first bullet point in [Advantages of Dynamic Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/advantages-of-dynamic-linking), whose contents I reproduce below:

> - Multiple processes that load the same DLL at the same base address share a single copy of the DLL in physical memory. Doing this saves
>     system memory and reduces swapping.

In summary, if there is a single copy of a DLL in memory, how can it be loaded into an application's memory space?

Comment: Windows is a demand-paged **virtual** memory operating system.  A process uses virtual memory, the code in **physical** memory can be mapped into any process that uses it.  The underlying OS object is a memory-mapped file, mapping occurs on demand.  Loading a DLL merely requires reserving the address space and setting up the paging tables.